# Using Apache Camel Simple in custom Camel Components

Tags: apache-camel

I am creating my own custom component for doing various operations. I would like to know what is the best approach to be able to evaluate Simple in my uri, exactly in the remaining and the options. That way I can provide more flexibility. I have already taken a look to http://camel.apache.org/expression.html but I am not really sure how to integrate the evaluation into my java code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What component would you create ? You can try to find a similar component and look at the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how the file component uses simple/file language for the fileName option.

See the source code of these methods/classes

- org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileEndpoint#setFileName
- org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer#evaluateFileExpression

Comment: I have already taken a look and that's what I was looking for. Thanks as always!